# Should DLLs have their own configuration files?

Tags: dll, configuration

Apologies if this is a duplicate, but I've not managed to find this question being asked directly.

The general opinion here (that's me and him across from me) is that they shouldn't, the reason being that DLLs can be shared; therefore the idea of having application-specific information in a DLL is nonsense. If the information is not application-specific, then constants can be used.

A further question is, assuming that DLLs do not have their own config file, whether DLLs should use the configuration files of the executable that loaded the DLL, or instead be passed the relevant data as part of some kind of constructor. Our opinion here is the latter, as it makes it more testable, the downside being that it will sometimes be necessary to pass a significant amount of data to the dll.

Opinions?

Comment: I'm guessing you mean .NET DLL's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no reason why you can't have the best of both worlds in terms of "simple to configure with config files" and "testable". Have a static method which can create instances from the configuration file, but also provide a constructor for more control and testability. The static method would just grab the settings and call the constructor.

I believe it's possible to create settings classes for DLLs just like any other project, and then you just need to put the actual text into the application's config file instead of one for the DLL. Basically ignore the app.config generated for the library project, except to use as a template for the application's central one.

Alternatively, use something like Spring.NET to manage this sort of thing :)

Answer (score 0):

Usually, I guess you should pass relevant information to the functions you're calling or set relevant properties in objects you're creating that are defined within the DLL. I guess that's why .NET does not really support config files for DLLs (you can create them, but they'll not be used when running).

I have one scenario, where DLLs are reading a config file, but that is very special: The .NET DLL exports objects as COM objects for use by Microsoft Navision. It communicates with a factoring bank using an XML-RPC interface.

While the DLL is installed on every user's machine, the configuration for the interface is common to all users, so I have a configuration placed on a network drive that's mapped on every PC and the configuration (URL, credentials, etc.) is read from that common file.

Whether that's good practice is up to the reader, but in that scenario having a common config file just made sense...